# Question about wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

http://demo.thethemefoundry.com/traction/#post-183

Which wordpress plugin is this, to have post image on the left side and shortened version of your post on the right, and read more button below?

Thank you

Comment: why close this question?

Comment: Because it is not a programming question

Comment: He just didn't ask it in the right manner.

Comment: @John Conde I can either customize it manually, or find a plugin so its somewhat programming related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be many different plugins, but you could just place your image first, align left, then use this plugin to get the "Read More"...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sem-fancy-excerpt/

I use this one on my Wordpress, makes the small excerpt nice and neat.

Comment: I found it fw-post-image , thats the name of the plugin with combination of that one its a killer :D

Answer (score 1):

Hey. I think they don't use any plugin to get post-style like this. You can use WordPress 2,9's new feature - **Post Thumbnail Images** and aling image left, use excerpt's for text and style cool read more link or button style. Read this great tutorial for the last one - **[Display Post Excerpts Only in WordPress](http://lorelle.wordpress.com/2006/07/19/display-post-excerpts-only-in-wordpress/)**

I hope this will help you to get what you want ;)